# How do I get Django Admin to delete files when I remove an object from the database/model when there's two classes?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I use this to delete a file and it works:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=mymodel)
def submission_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.file.delete(False)
```

but I have two models with files and when I copy paste that code and just changing the name of my model it doesn't work anymore like this:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=mymodel)
def submission_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.file.delete(False)

@receiver(post_delete, sender=mymodel2)
def submission_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.file2.delete(False)
```

how can I fix that?

EDIT: I just discovered that the last one works but the first one it doesn't so how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

did you check which model deletes first.
try to change position of these two functions.

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=mymodel2)
def submission_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.file2.delete(False)

@receiver(post_delete, sender=mymodel)
def submission_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.file.delete(False)
```

Comment: I just changed between their positions and it's always the last one that gets deleted

Comment: can you send me images of view, model, url and form

Answer (score 0):

I had to just rename the two functions lol, they had the same name that why.

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=mymodel)
def submission_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.file.delete(False)

@receiver(post_delete, sender=mymodel2)
def submission_de(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.file2.delete(False)
```